# If column X contains value, add column Y value to worksheet range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, however I require specific help with the development of the required VBA code.

The scenario:
A membership database (worksheet "Members") contains members details including whether they are "Active" or not.

I am trying to make the program look down Column C; if cell contains "ACTIVE" then copy corresponding Column A value to a 2nd worksheet template range, "active members".

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?  If it's that you don't know *any* VBA, then unfortunately this is not really the place to learn.  If you're having a problem with existing code then it's best to add that to your question for others to comment on.

Comment: You can do it by excel function. Show your data.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy all active users to the second worksheet called `Active Members`

```
Sub copyActive()
Dim counter, RowNo As Long

counter = 1
RowNo = 1

    Do Until Sheets("Members").Cells(counter, 1) = ""
    If UCase(Sheets("Members").Cells(counter, 3)) = "ACTIVE" Then
    Sheets("Active Members").Cells(RowNo, 1) = Sheets("Members").Cells(counter, 1)
    RowNo = RowNo + 1
    counter = counter + 1
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This code does work however I'm finding it doesn't copy all active users, it's doing approximately 60% of them instead

Comment: Can you find an example of a row that DOES NOT copy?  Please post the data